# Analytic function and Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I want to ask a question:
Let $B$ is an open subset of $A$ and $f(x)=\sum c_nx^n$ for every $x$ in $B$. Can I conclude that $f(x)=\sum c_nx^n$ for every $x$ in $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take disjoint two disjoint open sets $C$ and $D$. Let $B=C$ and $A= C\cup D$. Can yo see why your assertion fails in this case?

Hint: take $f=1$ on $C$ and $f=0$ on $D$.

If $A$ is connected then the conclusion holds. This is because $g(x) =\sum c_n z^{n}$ defines an anaytic function on $A$. Since $f=g$ in $B$ and $B$ has a limit point in $A$ it follows that $f=g$ on $A$.

Comment: Very good logic!

Comment: What happens if A is connected? I think this counterexample will not work?

Comment: @spyer I have edited my answer.